# Maximum item matching from pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matching

I have a DataFrame.
Something like this:

```
| Idx | name  | age | sex | birth month | birth day |
|   - | -     | -   | -   | -           | -         |
|   0 | Mike  | 10   | w   | 8           | ?         |
|   1 | Julia | 10  | w   | ?           | ?         |
|   2 | ?     | 10  | w   | ?           | ?         |
```

```
(? : “don’t care”)
query: (age : 10, sex : w, birth month : 3 )
```

I want to find the column which has maximum matching with the query. So the answer will be “idx 1”.

How can I find the answer quickly?
I just compared the query using for loop.
But it must be a bad way.

- I don’t want to count the “?” mark!

Comment: Shouldn't idx2 be also the answer as it also has two matches?

Comment: @Chris yes, but i wanna find only one answer which has maximum condition quantification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, then what you are looking for in the row with the most matches in the columns that you specify.  Such that given you're example (but extended a bit further)

```
| Idx | name  | age | sex | birth month | birth day |
|   - | -     | -   | -   | -           | -         |
|   0 | Mike  | ?   | m   | 8           | ?         |
|   1 | Julia | 10  | w   | ?           | ?         |
|   2 | ?     | 10  | w   | ?           | ?         |
|   3 | Julia | 10  | m   | ?           | ?         |
```

If you query for name = Julia, age=10 you would get both idx (1 and 3) but if you further qualify your query to ask for name= Julia, age=10 and sex ='w' then you would only get IDX 1.  Is this correct?  If so, then I think this will work.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Idx': [0,1,2, 3], 
    'name': ['Mike ', 'Julia ', '?', 'Julia'], 
    'sex': ['m', 'w', 'w', 'm'],
    'age': [42, 52, 52, 10]})

# Here specify the full set of parameters that makes a good match
query_params = [('name','Julia'), ('sex','w'), ('age',52)]

# Now build a mask from all of the query parameters
mask = pd.DataFrame([df[x[0]]==x[1] for x in query_params])
mask
          0      1      2
name  False  False  False
sex   False   True   True
age   False   True   True

# We'll transpose these series to make it more readable, then sum up the number of 'matches' for each row
mask = mask.T
mask['count'] = mask.sum(axis=1)
mask

    name    sex    age  count
0  False  False  False      0
1  False   True   True      2
2  False   True   True      2

# Now it's just a matter of indexing back into the original dataframe where the mask matches the most fields
df.iloc[mask['count'].idxmax()]

Idx           1
name     Julia
sex           w
age          52
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to do this is to count ? on each row in its own column:

```
df['matchingscore'] = (df == '?').T.sum()
df = df.sort_values('matchingscore')
```

Now apply your filter, the least ? rows will be at the top.

So the dataframe becomes:

```
    name age sex birthmonth birthday  matchingscore
0   Mike   ?   m          8        ?              2
1  Julia  10   w          ?        ?              2
2      ?  10   w          ?        ?              3
```

And then filter is applied:

```
>>>df[(df.age == 10)&(df.sex == 'w')]:

    name age sex birthmonth birthday  matchingscore
1  Julia  10   w          ?        ?              2
2      ?  10   w          ?        ?              3
```

The only confusing thing here is that "matchingscore" is inversed: lower is better, since it counts ? fields.

Comment: Thank you! 1. Matching score could be measured by string, except ? mark. 2. What if the query is “name:Julia, birth month : 3”

Answer (score 0):

First create `dict` using `collections.defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

q = '(age : 10, sex : w, birth month : 3 )'
q_d = defaultdict(lambda : list('?'))
for s in re.findall('\((.+)\)', q)[0].strip().split(','):
    k, v = s.strip().split(' : ')
    q_d[k].append(v)
```

This way, `?` will always exist in comparison.

Then use `pandas.DataFrame.isin`:

```
df[df[q_d].isin(q_d).all(1)].head(1)
```

Output:

```
  Idx   name age sex birth month birth day
2   1  Julia  10   w           ?         ?
```

Comment: How about “don’t care mark”? What if the query is (name : julia, birth month : 3)

Comment: @haha Try the new version ;)

Answer (score 0):

A slight modification of @Chris's original answer should work:

```py
query = {'age': 10, 'sex': 'w', 'birth month': 3}
df.loc[df.eq(pd.Series(query)).sum(axis='columns').idxmax()]
```

That gets you the row with largest number of matches. If there's a tie, it returns the first one:

```
name           Julia
age               10
sex                w
birth month        ?
birth day        NaN
Name: 1, dtype: object
```